# Existence of a meromorphic extension of special sums of monomials

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

Let $(f_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\lim_{k \to \infty}f_k =0$. Consider $$ F(z):=\sum_{k\geq 0} z^{k}f_k.$$ Of course $F$ is holomorphic on the unit disk. If $f_n =1\forall n$ one would have a meromorphic extension of $F$ to $\mathbb{C}$ with a simple pole at $z=1$.

My question now is: Is it still true that $F$ can be meromorphically extended to some domain containing $\{z:\|z\|<1+\epsilon\}$ for some $\epsilon>0$ s.t. it has at most a pole at $z=1$ ? (More generally: Is there anything one can say about meromorphic extensions of $F$ ?) I am thankful for any suggestion...

I know that the answer to the question is negative in general if $f_n$ is only bounded instead of convergent to $0$. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: the answer is no in the sense that the unit circle may easily be the natural boundary here, while $F$ may extend to the unit circle to be even infinitely differentiable in the real sense as for example $f_{2^n}=\frac{1}{2^{mn}}, f_k=0, k \ne 2^n, m\ge 1$ fixed gives $F$ with natural boundary the unit circle and $m-1$ differentiable in the real sense on the unit circle, and with more care we can get a $C^{\infty}$ on the unit circle example

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you explain why your example has the unit circle as natural boundary? Thank you!

Comment: If it would be analytic (or meromorphic for that matter if we have meromorphic extension)  on any open set containing a point on the unit circle, its $m$th derivative would be too and that is more or less the well known example of analytic functions with unit circle as natural boundary (as it converges to infinity at  $r\zeta, r \to 1$ and $\zeta$ any root of unity of order power of two and those are dense in the unit circle

Comment: Thank you! If I understood you correctly, you argue that $F$ like you construct it, has divergences one the unit circle. I possibly made a slight mistake stating my question then: I allow divergences on the unit circle (like it would be the case for $f_k=1$). My question is if it is possible to find a meromorphic extension $F_{ext}$ of $F$ beyond the unit circle making such divergences to poles of a meromorphic function. If your example is still working, I did not understand it (yet).. Sorry!!

Comment: The unit circle is natural boundary meaning that the function is singular at any point on it, so there is no analytic/meromorphic extension beyond the unit circle; if you pick any arbitrary analytic function on the unit disc which has the unit circle as a natural boundary and integrate it enough times (or more or less equivalently replace it's coefficients $f_k$ with $f_k/k^m$ for fixed large $m$ you get another analytic function with natural boundary the circle but coefficients small

Comment: Ahh. Yes, now I get it. Thank you again!